# MacOS Monterey and Android Studio Bumblebee, "Git is not installed"

Tags: git, android-studio, macos-monterey

After upgrade upgrading Android Studio to Bumblebee version, I encountered this error.

Xcode has been installed, but currently is uninstalled.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

1. Follow the suggestion, Terminal run `xcode-select --install`
2. Then run `sudo xcode-select --reset`, this will reset its path
3. Update Android Studio > Preference > Version Control > Git > Path to `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/git`
4. Invalidate cache and restart the android studio (optional)
5. Work fine now